# Including the build of one repo to another repo in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, ant, azure-pipelines, war, ear

I have a repo in Azure devops which is using 'ant all' command to build an ear file. This ear file contain should a war file built from another repo in the azure.
How can I include this war file in the build?

Thanks.

Comment: How's your issue going? Is there any update?

Comment: Yeah, Thanks . Its resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your war file is built from code hosted in another repo and not is a part of the repo itself. You can publish pipeline artifact and download it in your next pipeline. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) you have doc article about this. And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) description of the task itself.

In short to publish you should add code like this:

```yaml
steps:
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/WebApp
  artifact: WebApp
```

and to download:

```yaml
# Download artifacts from a specific pipeline.
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    source: 'specific'
    project: 'FabrikamFiber'
    pipeline: 12
    runVersion: 'latest'
```

Comment: Even I'm facing similar error, this answer really helped !! But, would like to clarify one thing, Pipeline#2 is dependent on #1(So, Pipeline which publish the artifact should run before consumer pipeline) Do we need to manually run these two pipelines as per the order Or any linking can be done ?

Comment: Actually you can use resource trigger, to run second pipeline after first one. Please check [pipeline resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pipeline-resource)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the war file is already in another repo in the same organization, you could check [multiple checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops), by using multiple checkout steps in your pipeline, you can fetch and check out other repositories in addition to the one you use to store your YAML pipeline.

```
steps:
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization
- checkout: self
```